# Why does my React component remain in the DOM after navigating to another page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a simple app with a home screen, a blog master list, and then blog detail page. Navigating from the home screen to the blog list and back works as expected. When I click on one of the blog posts the app navigates to the page and renders the blog post. But when I go back to the blog master list the blog post is now at the very bottom of the blog list. And if I then navigate back to the home page the same thing, the blog post is in the DOM behind the home page graphic.

I'm using react router 4.1.

Does it have to do with my **route setup**?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import NavBar from './components/NavBar'
import Blog from './pages/blog'
import Home from './pages/home'
import Post from './pages/post'
import './css/App.css'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
          <div className="App">
            <NavBar />
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
            <Route path='/blog' component={Blog} />
            <Route path='/post/:slug' component={Post} />
          </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Or with my **post component**?

```
import React from 'react'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'
import NavBar from '../components/NavBar'
import dateUtils from '../utilities/DateAndTime'

const classNames = require('classnames')


class Post extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            blogObject: null,
            fetchBlogObject: false
        }

        this.fetchBlogObject = this.fetchBlogObject.bind(this)
        this.createMarkup = this.createMarkup.bind(this)
        this.assignStyleToCoverImage = this.assignStyleToCoverImage.bind(this)
        this.formatDateString = this.formatDateString.bind(this)

    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.fetchBlogObject()
    }


    componentWillReceiveProps() {
        this.fetchBlogObject()
    }

    fetchBlogObject() {

            console.log('fetching')

            this.setState({ fetchBlogObject: true })

            fetch(`*******************`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log(responseJson)
                this.setState({ blogObject: responseJson.object })
            })


    }


    createMarkup(stringToConvertToHtml) {
        return { __html: stringToConvertToHtml }
    }


    assignStyleToCoverImage() {

        const style = {
            background: `url(${this.state.blogObject.metadata.hero.url})`,
            height: '35vh',
            backgroundSize: 'cover',
            backgroundPosition: 'center'
        }

        return style

    }


    formatDateString(dateString) {
        console.log(dateString)

        const d = `${dateUtils.returnMonthFromISODateString(dateString)} ${dateUtils.returnDateNumberFromISOString(dateString)}, ${dateUtils.returnFullYearFromISOString(dateString)} by Phil Andrews`
        return d
    }

    render() {


        const postContainerClasses = classNames({
            'post-container': true
        })

        const postBodyClasses = classNames({
            'post-body': true
        })

        return (

            <div>
                <NavBar />

                {this.state.blogObject ?

                    <div className={postContainerClasses} >
                        <div className='header-image' style={this.assignStyleToCoverImage(this.state.blogObject)} />
                        <div className='post-body-padding'>
                            <div className='post-header-info'>
                                <h1 className='post-title'>{this.state.blogObject.title}</h1>
                                <h4 className='post-date'>{this.formatDateString(this.state.blogObject.created_at)}</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div className={postBodyClasses} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup(this.state.blogObject.content)} />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                : <div>Loading...</div>

                }

            </div>

        )

    }
}

export default Post
```

Or with my **blog list button action** for navigating to a post page?

```
<Link id={this.props.blogObject.slug} to={`/post/${this.props.blogObject.slug}`}>
    <button className='blog-button' style={buttonStyle} id={this.props.blogObject.slug} />
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it would continue to render the entire component but if I get rid of the `<NavBar />` in the `post` component the issue goes away.

**Not working**:

```
 return (

            <div>
                <NavBar />

                {this.state.blogObject ?

                    <div className={postContainerClasses} >
                        <div className='header-image' style={this.assignStyleToCoverImage(this.state.blogObject)} />
                        <div className='post-body-padding'>
                            <div className='post-header-info'>
                                <h1 className='post-title'>{this.state.blogObject.title}</h1>
                                <h4 className='post-date'>{this.formatDateString(this.state.blogObject.created_at)}</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div className={postBodyClasses} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup(this.state.blogObject.content)} />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                : <div>Loading...</div>

                }

            </div>

        )
```

**Working**:

```
 return (

            <div>

                {this.state.blogObject ?

                    <div className={postContainerClasses} >
                        <div className='header-image' style={this.assignStyleToCoverImage(this.state.blogObject)} />
                        <div className='post-body-padding'>
                            <div className='post-header-info'>
                                <h1 className='post-title'>{this.state.blogObject.title}</h1>
                                <h4 className='post-date'>{this.formatDateString(this.state.blogObject.created_at)}</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div className={postBodyClasses} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup(this.state.blogObject.content)} />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                : <div>Loading...</div>

                }

            </div>

        )
```